# MySQL which is done first - filtering the WHERE conditions or calculating fields?

Tags: mysql

When performing a MySQL query, is all the data filtered by the WHERE conditions before any fields are calculated?

I have an application where I need to order by distance but need to work out the distances from lat/lng in the query ([found this which should cover that part of it](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL) (page 8)) but it mentions that the query is fairly slow. I want to know if MySQL will work out the distance for every database entry and then filter those results, or if the results will be filtered first?

**EDIT:**

I didn't make it quite clear - I only need to order the results at this stage. Filtering by distance would be good too but that will always be secondary to other criteria - i.e. the type would always need to be hotel before it mattered how close it was to the co-ordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHERE works directly on the rows, that's also the reason why you can't specify column aliases in WHERE clause. It would cause an unknown column error.

You could use HAVING or a subquery. In both cases the result will be calculated for all rows, then filtered.

**UPDATE:**

You have to filter by distance, right? So you can't filter rows first, then calculate distance. But what you can do, is to use the spatial extension. Then you'll have spatial indexes which could make your queries pretty fast, I guess (never had anything to do with things like this).

Read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html).

**UPDATE 2:**

Actually I don't get what your question is at all. You want to order by something you have to calculate first. So what's the question? Will it be fast? I don't know. All I can tell is, that no index can be used since MySQL does not support indexes on calculated columns. Probably a temporary table to sort whatever data you're getting will be used, too, depends on how much data it is. 
I'd suggest **try things out**.

Just do

```
SELECT coordA, coordB
FROM whereever
ORDER BY coordA - coordB
```

and that's it. When you have problems then, ask again.

To filter later

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT coordA, coordB, coordA - coordB AS distance
FROM whereever
ORDER BY distance
) sq
WHERE distance > $foo
```

When that's too slow play around with indexes and/or the extension mentioned earlier.

Comment: Ok, thanks. so would you say that fetching the data with the WHERE conditions with one query, then using a second query to work out the distances and order the results based on the first query would be the best way of going about this (performance wise)?

Comment: I don't have to filter by distance like the article I linked to - I was a little unclear - I need to order by distance but there are also other criteria that need to be met. If I could filter by these other criteria first then it would save working out the distance for entries which will never be included right? In theory, I could then filter by distance later if I needed to but on the smaller sample. (Added a couple of sentences to the original question to clarify)

Comment: Ok... the original question was which part of the query behind the scenes which you answered. I was just trying to clarify with my comment that performing the calculation on a smaller filtered data set would probably be faster than calculating for every single row then filtering. The application isn't currently built, I'm trying to plan based the answer is all. Your original answer answers my original question so I will mark it as answered. Thanks